# Customizing Liferay error messages

Tags: error-handling, liferay, portlet

I'm developing a portlet for Liferay 6.1. At some point I'm evaluating input from a form. In case of invalid input, I'm displaying an error message with `<liferay-ui:error>`. Ideally I would like to include the invalid value in that message.

Example: There is a text input that is supposed to accept only numbers. The user enters the letter "A" and submits the form. The portlet displays "Sorry, 'A' is not a number." (I'm aware that I could simply check that on the client. In my case it's more complex data, though.)

Is there a way to use the value parameter of `add(PortletRequest portletRequest, String key, Object value)` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't find such clearly solution and have used my own Error-Output:

```
<%
    String myError = (String)request.getAttribute("my-custom-error");
%>
<c:if test="<%= (myError != null) %>">
        <div class="portlet-msg-error">
            <%= myError %>
        </div>
</c:if>
```

The css-class "portlet-msg-error" come from liferay and is for default error-rendering.

On the backend put the "my-custom-error" value to the request:

```
actionRequest.setAttribute("my-custom-error", "Sorry, " + value + " is not a number.");
```

But I would prefer some solution with using of liferay-error-tag.

Comment: That's the way I would have gone also. I was just hoping that there's a simpler way to do it using the components already present in Liferay.